# Next.js: height: 100vh not working when width: is set at 100vh on mobile

Tags: css, next.js

I know that it is bad practice to use height: 100vh on mobile for multiple reasons. However, how come height: 100vh is not respected when it is coupled with width:100vh in Next.js? I get a square that doesn't take the full height of the page / browser. It only happens on mobile, not when I resize my window. The same happens in Chrome and Firefox.

```css
section {
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
 }
```

```html
<section></section>
```

Comment: Your snippet is working perfectly OK for me on Safari IOS 15. Of course I have to scroll down slightly to see the whole thing because of the browser setting default margins. What mobiles are you testing on?

Answer (score 2):

`height: 100vh;` means 100% virtual height.
For width, use:

```css
width: 100vw;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want 100vh for my width, to make a square for example. It seems like this isn't a Next.JS issue but a new bug from Chrome.